# Back Button Issue

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, back

I am struggling with Back button link.

For back button, I am using Back to go to the previous page. This works absolutely fine in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox. In IE it stays on the same page and in Firefox I get "Page Expired" message.

I have a hint of a problem but i don't know the solution.

So my trace of URL is :

`/xyz/client/auth/createIDForm.do which redirects xyz/client/pub/redirectByURL.jsp?nextURL=/auth/setQnAForm.do`

Now the landing page is `xyz/client/auth/setQnAForm.do` however the back button on this page is having problem like I have mentioned above.

I think its going back to `rediretByURL.jsp`?`nextURL=/auth/setQnAForm.do` and refreshes the same page however in Chrome.I think the back page is loading from cache.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Why won't you add manully a link to the home page?

Comment: I don't want to redirect back button to a Home page, but to previous page.

Comment: Shouldn't the back button link point to /xyz/client/auth/createIDForm.do

Comment: Yes you are right, it should redirect to  /xyz/client/auth/createIDForm.do but that's not happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one

```
<button onclick="goBack()">previous page</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 )
    {
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1)
    {
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) 
    {
         window.history.go(-1);
    }
    else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) //IF IE > 10
    {
      window.location.href="yourPageLink";
    } 


   }
    </script>
```

Comment: Its giving me the same behaviour like I originally explained.

Comment: did you try window.location.href = "previousPageLink"

Comment: Nabli, above line is working for IE but not for Chrom and Mozilla. Can you suggest me something which can work on all ?